# Intel Atom powered tablet running android. Can It run a Linux Distro?

Tags: linux, tablet, x86-processors

I recently got my hands onto a Neso N810 i7 (ECS TA80TA1 rebranded) tablet, powered by an Intel Atom Z3735E processor, 1GB of DDR3, and 16GB of internal storage. It runs Android 4.2.2, and given the age, it performs really well. Only thing is that most apps can't be installed/aren't compatible, so that makes it pretty useless.

IMO, specwise, this tablet is completely capable of running most distros that provide a lightweight gui.

The problem is actually firmware. Since I thought that, because it is "just a notebook without keyboard", I was going to be able to find a BIOS or UEFI, and a proper boot menu that would let me boot from any usb flash drive plugged into the usb otg port. But, I was surprised to see that, there is no such thing (i think) as a BIOS on this tablet. Instead, there is this thing called "DroidBoot Provision OS" that looks to be a bootloader of some sort. I wasn't able to find anything useful regarding linux installation using droidboot. Other tablets seem to have a bios screen when doing the same key combination as I did (Power + Volume Up).

I was wondering if someone could orient me a little bit on what this droidboot thing is, and if it can be used to replace android with linux, or in any case, to even get rid of droidboot and install a BIOS/UEFI

Comment: You won't find a BIOS or UEFI, because Android devices don't have such a software component. Most Android devices use bootloader, however this part  is not part of AOSP and not "standardized" by Google Android, therefore every manufacturer use a different bootloader.